# Why are the resulting date records from this DATEADD() expansion (union) query out of order after inserting into a table?

Tags: sql

The below query should (I believe) create a list of dates + hours in ascending order between the specified start and end datetimes, and then I want to insert them into a temporary table. I expect the table to contain all the new records in ascending order, as the select would return by itself. In practice, the table records begin at the start date and increment as expected up to March 8th, 2023 hour 19 and then the next record is August 14th, 2023 hour 12. The missing dates appear at the end of the table. Even if I try to subsequently sort the dates with another query, they are still not in the correct order. Why is that?

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME = '2023-02-17 00:00:00'
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME = '2023-12-31 00:00:00';

CREATE TABLE #NewDates (ExpandedDateTime DATETIME);

WITH ExpDates AS
    (
    SELECT @StartDateTime AS ExpandedDateTime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(HOUR, 1, ExpandedDateTime)
    FROM    ExpDates
    WHERE   DATEADD(HOUR, 1, ExpandedDateTime) <= @EndDateTime
    )
INSERT INTO #NewDates
SELECT  ExpandedDateTime
FROM    ExpDates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

SELECT * FROM #NewDates
```

[Results from temp table query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFgAn.png)

Comment: i tried the same query on my machine. it is giving me exact result as you wanted. is there anything more you want to add.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b2adb/1

check this fiddle, it is also giving the records in order

Comment: Relational data bases *do not* guarantee any kind of record order in their result sets unless you explicitly specify it with an Order By clause in your SQL.  Since there is no Order By anywhere in your SQL, the DBMS  is free to return records in any order that it deems most efficient.

Comment: Hi @RamSingh, thanks. Nothing to add I guess. Appreciate the example. That's what I expected. Any idea why it could work one way in that instance and another on my machine?